# custom UITableViewCells and proper use of prepareForReuse and removeFromSuperview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have some custom UITableViewCell's and when I scroll, the custom labels and imageviews become very convoluted. Like this:

[image]

When I read the docs for prepareForReuse, it's unclear what this method is supposed to do. It says:

> For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell 
>   that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and
>   selection state. The table view's delegate in
>   tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should always reset all content when
>   reusing a cell.

However, in my custom cells, I have to remove all the labels and imageviews. I currently have this in prepareForReuse in my custom table cell.

I have three questions:
1. Is the doubling up of content to be expected? Or am I doing something seriously wrong? 
2. If normal, is the only way to handle this by removingFromSuperview the elements? I have tried setting them to nil but that doesn't fully work.
3. Would prepareForReuse be the proper place for this to removeFromSuperview? Such as:

```
    import UIKit

    class EKMenuItemCell: UITableViewCell {

  var screenWidth:CGFloat = 0
  var screenHeight:CGFloat = 0
  let leftMIPadding:CGFloat = 40.0
  let rightMIPadding:CGFloat = 90.0
  let rightPricePadding:CGFloat = 60.0
  var mainItemWidth:CGFloat = 0


  var miHeaderLabel = UILabel()
  var miDetailLabel = UILabel()
  var miPriceLabel = UILabel()

  func updateCell(menuItem: EKMenuItem){
    var bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    self.screenWidth = bounds.size.width
    self.screenHeight = bounds.size.height

    self.mainItemWidth = self.screenWidth - (self.leftMIPadding + self.rightMIPadding)
    self.renderMenuItemHeader(menuItem)
    self.renderMenuItemDetail(menuItem)
    //self.renderMenuItemPrice(menuItem)
  }

  func renderMenuItemHeader(menuItem: EKMenuItem){
    miHeaderLabel=UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(leftMIPadding,0, self.mainItemWidth, CGFloat.max))
    miHeaderLabel.text=menuItem.header
    miHeaderLabel.numberOfLines=0
    miHeaderLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    miHeaderLabel.sizeToFit()
    miHeaderLabel.frame = CGRectMake(leftMIPadding, 10, self.mainItemWidth, miHeaderLabel.frame.size.height)
    miHeaderLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    miHeaderLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    menuItem.cellHeight = miHeaderLabel.frame.size.height + 10
    self.contentView.addSubview(miHeaderLabel)
  }


  func renderMenuItemDetail(menuItem: EKMenuItem){
    //println("here is my menuItem.detail")

    miDetailLabel=UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(leftMIPadding, 0, self.mainItemWidth, CGFloat.max))
    miDetailLabel.text=menuItem.detail
    miDetailLabel.numberOfLines=0
    miDetailLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    miDetailLabel.sizeToFit()
    miDetailLabel.frame = CGRectMake(leftMIPadding, (miHeaderLabel.frame.size.height + 20), self.mainItemWidth, miDetailLabel.frame.size.height)
    miDetailLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    miDetailLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    menuItem.cellHeight += miDetailLabel.frame.size.height + 10.0
    self.contentView.addSubview(miDetailLabel)

  }


      override func prepareForReuse() {
        println("here i am in prepareForReuse")
        miDetailLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        miHeaderLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        super.prepareForReuse()
      }
```

#### edit 1

Here's the cellForRowAtIndexPath in the controller:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  let tmpTableItem = self.tableItems[indexPath.row]
  if let menuHeader = tmpTableItem as? EKMenuHeader {
    let tableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MenuHeaderCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EKMenuHeaderCell
    tableViewCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    tableViewCell.updateCell(menuHeader)
    return tableViewCell
  } else if let menuItem = tmpTableItem as? EKMenuItem {
    let tableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MenuItemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EKMenuItemCell
    tableViewCell.updateCell(menuItem)
    return tableViewCell
  }
  let tableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
  return tableViewCell
}
```

#### edit 2

Per Wain's comment, when setting strings to "", the borders that I apply get all out of whack. It just seems like this is janky and performance is fine removing from subviews on modern iPhones.

[image]

Comment: can you paste your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method

Comment: @BabulPrabhakar  this is done

Comment: Could you post the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method as well? Where are you adding the labels?

Comment: Have you checked whether the prepareForReuse method is getting called before cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: thx @ZeMoon , yes `prepareForReuse` is definitely being called.

Comment: 'It works fine on modern devices' isn't an excuse for inefficient code, you're reusing cells and you should be reusing the cell subviews. You should also look at using auto layout. Your current label size calculation doesn't consider the available width...

Comment: @Wain I agree about the inefficient code comment - that's why I'm asking.  Auto Layout is for another day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be removing the views, because then you incur the cost of recreating them. Instead you should just be setting the text to nil, but even then if every cell always has text you don't need to do that because the new text will replace the old before the cell is visible. Most use cases don't require you to use `prepareForReuse`.

The duplication suggests that you are adding new views all the time and not updating your variables so each time you try to remove them nothing actually happens.

Comment: thx Wain, that's how I thought it should work but it's never worked that way for me. Agreed about recreating the subviews being bad but setting them to nil doesn't achieve anything. This is the tableView that is returning different custom cells so it's possible that there is something unusual going on.

Comment: Don't set the views to nil, that will only break your cell. You should never be adding new subviews to your custom cell each time it's used.

Comment: so, I update edit #2, when i apply borders to the view's layer, the results are at best unpredictable. All of these are variable line numbers in the UILabel and I feel like there's unpredictable results.

Comment: How are you sizing the cells? Your label height calculation doesn't consider the available width so it looks like nothing is going to match up (and that's what you see on screen).

Comment: i write the height to the cell's model (either an item or header to a property called cellHeight). My co-worker said I would need to compute out the dynamic height seperately from the cell (would obviously be a performance issue there). I think it's just a shortcoming of using UITableViewCell's with multi-line labels.

Comment: That's why Apple introduced auto-height cells when working with auto-layout in iOS 8.

Comment: thx - I'll look into that. I didn't write the initial code and we have a set of animations / effects on the layers (hence the issue with doubling up of layers). I'll see if we can achieve the same effect via AutoLayout but when this app was written, this apparently was to be the only feasible way. I think our best path is to take the minor hit on recreating the subviews via our current technique.